# Spring Tests Without Migrations/DBs?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spock, spring-test

I'm using Spock with Spring Test for Unit Testing controllers and services - but in order for the Unit Tests to successfully execute a connection to a DB is required. In all tests I've mocked out any required repositories - so there is no dependency on the DBs.

Does anyone know how to successfully execute tests without migrations and an active connection to a DB?

I've annotated all test classes with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)`

and I'm using `MockMvc` for mocking the MVC setup:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .setControllerAdvice(new RestResponseIssueHandler())
                .addFilter(new SessionFilter())
                .build();
```

Comment: you'll usually have a replacement db for testing, e.g. an inmemory H2 database e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing - that way your repositories just work as usual

Comment: Did you try `@WebMvcTest`, you can declare only one controller, as in example which you are presented. Another required services you can easily declared by `@Import` and `@MockBean` if required.